# How to check, which files are changed by specific Windows Update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'd like to know, what specific changes are being introduced by specified Windows Update update (in terms, kbxxxxxxxx).

Other option: I'd like to know, which update introduced specific file.

Reason: I'd like to cleanly remove update with the get-Windows-10 app and **I don't have any of widely known updates with GWX stuff installed**. I have to figure out first, which update introduced these files and scheduler entries *again*.

Comment: KB3035583 installed the get windows 10 malware, just uninstall this update and all will be good.

Comment: @Moab: Let me repeat: **I don't have any of widely known updates with GWX stuff installed.** Including the infamous 3035583.

Comment: 305583 is the only update that installs GWX

Comment: @Moab This is not true. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072318

Comment: See if this helps remove gwx.  http://www.infoworld.com/article/2979572/microsoft-windows/gwx-stopper-an-easy-way-to-permanently-delete-get-windows-10-nagware-in-windows-7-and-81.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every Windows update is associated with a KB article that contains a list of updated or created files. That KB article is accessible at `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/#######` with all those `#`s replaced by the update number. (You can change `en-us` to your language code if you want.) For example, [here's one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3112148) that updates a bunch of timezone-related stuff. Some articles have the table in the article itself; others (like the linked one) have a link to download a CSV with the information.

If you don't trust that, you can download the standalone version of the update from the KB article. Extract it with the Windows Update Standalone Installer: `wusa FULL_PATH_TO_MSU /extract:FULL_PATH_TO_DEST_FOLDER`. For example:

```
wusa C:\Users\Ben\Downloads\Windows8.1-KB2693643-x64.msu /extract:C:\suspiciousUpdate
```

(For the curious, that "update" is the Remote Server Administration Tools package for Windows 8.1.)

Navigate to the destination folder. There might be a `PkgInstallOrder.txt`, which indicates that the update will run an executable in addition to doing the normal Component-Based Servicing stuff; you can look at that file to see exactly what will be done in what order. There will also be an XML document that lists the CAB packages that will be installed.

To get at the full list of files, you'll need to extract the `.cab`s. This can be done with WinRAR, but Windows Explorer can at least look into them. Inside each `.cab` is an XML document that lists the files that will be created in WinSxS. Use any web browser's search function to look for the names of suspicious files. The `.cab` will also contain a bunch of `.manifest` files, some of which have `<file>` entries, which create hardlinks outside of WinSxS.

You can torch the WUSA extraction folder when you're done looking around inside it.

Answer (score 1):

To see which files are part of an update, download the MSU from the [downloadcenter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download), extract the CAB from it with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) in C:\MSUFolder, next [extract the CAB with the `expand.exe` from Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928636) in a commandprompt by running those commands:

```
c: <ENTER>
cd c:\MSUFolder <ENTER>
expand -F:* Saved_MSU_File_Name.cab c:\MSUFolder <ENTER>
```

You all files gets extracted and you can look at all details, version information and more.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I figured out by myself, that Microsoft web pages contain detailed information about updates. I finally found out, which update is responsible for reintroducing that (censored) GWX stuff to my computer and it turned out, that it was [3072318](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072318).

I came up with an idea - I took a look at creation date of `C:\Windows\System32\GWX\GWX.exe` and matched it with list of installed updates. Fortunately, only 8 of them were installed at that date and careful examination of Microsoft articles revealed the one I was searching for. Already uninstalled, now only restart remains to free my notebook from this spam.

Answer (score 0):

1. extract msu
   `expand -f:* .\windows10.0-kb4489899-x64_c155ece4afbee219e7dfb83df67a7f2baf7c0d1d.msu .\your folder\
2. use 7zip to open cab file **Windows10.0-KB4487044-x64_PSFX.cab**.(just an example)
3. search your target in file **_manifest_.cix.xml** such as `xxx.dll`. looks like this

```
<File id="13003" name="wow64_microsoft-windows-zipfldr_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.107_none_f750bde8ef30fc65\f\zipfldr.dll" length="436" time="131939575275464258" attr="8224">
```

4. expand cab
   `expand -F:* Windows10.0-KB4487044-x64_PSFX.cab .\folder\cab`

you will see the file.